# Get style from PhoneResources and apply to new ListBox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have this style in PhoneApplicationPage.Resources:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <data:CarListView x:Key="carCollection" />
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
        ....
```

I am trying to add new ListBox with just one item to StackPanel. It just shows the name of class. I tried many ways. For example this:

```
ListBox lstBox = new ListBox();
CarListView view = new CarListView();
view.DataCollection.Add(new CarView("John", "Ferrari", "/Images/car_missing.jpg"));
lstBox.ItemsSource = view.DataCollection;
lstBox.Style = Application.Current.Resources["ListBoxItemStyle1"] as Style;
stackPanel.Children.Insert(0, lstBox);
```

Style and classes are alright. When I am not adding this in code but in xaml when page is loaded everything looks fine. How can I add new listbox from code with style from resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a sample where i create it all in the code and loads the style from the pages resources as in your sample

The XAML:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style  x:Key="myLBStyle"
            TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="Khaki" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="DarkSlateGray" />
        <Setter Property="Margin"
                Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="FontStyle"
                Value="Italic" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize"
                Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                Value="DarkGray" />
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Then i have an empty stackpanel where i add the listbox when the user click on a button

The code behind file:

```
    private void Test_Click_1(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox lstBox = new ListBox();
        List<string> data = new List<string>() { "one", "two", "three" };
        lstBox.ItemsSource = data;
        lstBox.ItemContainerStyle = this.Resources["myLBStyle"] as Style;
        MyStackPanel.Children.Insert(0, lstBox);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the ItemContainerStyle for the listboxitems, the Style is for the ListBox control!

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style  x:Key="myLBStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Khaki" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkSlateGray" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
        <ListBox Height="184"  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource myLBStyle}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             Margin="23,24,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="204" >
        <ListBox.Items>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item1" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item2" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item3" />
        </ListBox.Items>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Or in code:

```
listBox1.ItemContainerStyle = Application.Current.Resources["myLBStyle"] as Style;
```

Comment: I can't get your code working. I created listBox1 in code too but everything else I have same. Maybe there was other mistake. I solved this, that I have created ListBox in xaml hidden and when I need I show it.